# Can apache's PHP module affect C++ exceptions mechanism in other modules?

Tags: php, c++, apache, gcc

Setup:

1. Apache
2. php CLI
3. php_module.so for Apache
4. custom.so - my php extension with the following code (C++):

---

```
try {
    throw MyException("Bla-Bla");
} catch(const MyException& e) {
    LOG("got " << e.what());
}
```

The CLI version of PHP shows me "got Bla-Bla" where i expect it to (custom logger). But apache's PHP module run the same code and crash with uncaught exception:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'MyException'
  what(): Bla-Bla
[Wed Oct 07 14:12:41 2015] [notice] child pid 12614 exit signal Abort trap (6)
```

The php_module.so is build from the same sources as PHP CLI, but GCC flags used to compile php_module.so is unknown to me. Could some set of gcc flags (used for php_module.so compilation) affect custom.so exceptions behavior?

**UPDATE**
Seems to be GCC bug, because using clang solves the problem.